# How do I display the RTE/ Word Content in Asp.net webforms?

Tags: sitecore-api, fieldtype

We have bee using Sitecore 8.1 and in 8.1 we use the Field Types RTE and Word more . Due to some reason i had to use Asp.net Webforms not MVC. Can any one please help me how do i dispay the content of RTE and Word in Webforms ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display content of a `Rich Text` field in WebForms, you can use:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="Text" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<sc:Text Field="Text" runat="server" />
```

or

```
litText.Text = FieldRenderer.Render("Text"); // in code behind
```

**Sitecore documentation**: [Access a field using the FieldRender](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/access-a-field-using-the-fieldrender.html)

More information about field renderer and supported fields: [Which Sitecore fields can be rendered using a FieldRenderer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/which-sitecore-fields-can-be-rendered-using-a-fieldrenderer)